# Java script error on Safari and Chrome

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome, safari

I have a function that opens a popup menu. but on safari and Chrome i get this error but on IE it works fine. it looks like these browsers do not recognise ".document" im guessing. does any one know what the cause of it is?

**Error on Safari:**

> TypeError: Result of expression 'addressPopupMenu' [undefined] is not an object.

**Error on Chrome:**

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties 'document' of  undefined.

**The function:**

```
var addressPopupMenu = window.createPopup();



function showAddressPopup() {

        if(isDroppedDown == 0){

        var addressPopup = document.getElementById('addressFullSpan');

        addressPopupMenuBody = addressPopupMenu.document.body;

        addressPopupMenuBody.style.backgroundColor = "#29527A";

        var height = 0;
        var width = 0;

        if (addressPopup.innerHTML != '') {

            addressPopupMenuBody.innerHTML = addressPopup.innerHTML;

            if (addressPopupMenu.isOpen) {

                addressPopupMenu.hide();

            }

            addressPopupMenu.show(0, 0, 0, 0);

            height = addressPopupMenuBody.scrollHeight;

            width = addressPopupMenuBody.scrollWidth;

            addressPopupMenu.hide();

        } else {

            height = 0;

            width = 0;

        }

        var widthForResolution = 299;

        if (screen.width<=1024){

            widthForResolution = 235;

            }

        if(screen.width>=1280){

            widthForResolution = 299;

            }


        var link0 = document.getElementById('Pname');

        addressPopupMenu.show(84 , 105 , widthForResolution, 140, addressPopup); //left , top + width, height

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

window.createPopup() is a IE only function

Comment: whats the equivalent of it in safari, chrome etc, do you know?

Comment: @felix kling. where does it say its an IE only function. I just want to be 100% sure

Comment: @user521180: It is not stated explicitly. Just one guy wrote at the bottom that it is not available in Firefox, and Firefox itself has not documentation about this function. And if you go to the console on Safari and Chrome and type `window.createPopup`, you will get `undefined`. I think that is pretty sure ;)